# Using JS, How do I check an HTML DIV that isn't available without physically click on that element?

Tags: javascript

I'm playing a game where you have to click a small image

[image: Small Image with JS Event to open wheel window]

that opens up a window with a wheel on it.
[image: Window with Wheel]

Once that window opens, the HTML changes and the DIV I am looking for is there. In the image above you can see that right now under the START, says 3 gems. Before that it says FREE SPIN.

The first image to open this spin wheel window is a JS function that when clicked some Event is called thus this window opens.

What I am trying to do is create a button ( which I already have) that I can click that checks to see if this START button on this wheel is free or not. The issue is my button only works if this wheel window is open. I am trying to get it to work without it being open. I'm not sure what I'm looking for or how to do this. Looking for help or direction.

This works flawlessly the way I have it but only if I click the little image first to open the spinwheel window but I would like run this without clicking that image first. How would I go about this?

My button and my SpinWheel() function

```js
function SpinWheel() {

  // Get the element with the ID "freeforSpin"
  var freeforSpin = ById('freeforSpin');
  var gemforSpin = ById('gemforSpin');

  // If the element with the ID "freeforSpin" exists...
  if (freeforSpin) {
    // Check if the element with the ID "FreeSp" exists inside "freeforSpin"
    var FreeSp = freeforSpin.querySelector("#FreeSp");
    if (FreeSp) {
      // If it does, call cm.SpinController.doSpin() and update the button text to "FREE SPIN"
      cm.SpinController.doSpin();
      ById('mySpinButton').innerHTML = "FREE SPIN";
      return "FREE SPIN";
    }
  }

  // If the element with the ID "gemforSpin" exists...
  if (gemforSpin) {
    // Check if the element with the ID "costSp" exists inside "gemforSpin"
    var costSp = gemforSpin.querySelector("#costSp");
    if (costSp) {
      // If it does, update the button text to "3 GEMS TO SPIN" and return "3 GEMS TO SPIN"
      ById('mySpinButton').innerHTML = "No More Spins";
      return "No More Spins";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="mySpinButton" type="button" onclick="SpinWheel()">CHECK SPIN</button>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to make a [mcve]

Comment: Does `ById("FreeSp")` return the free spin regardless of it is visible or not? You could just test if it is visible,

Comment: @mplungjan The problem is this whole script is 50k lines long and it's not easy to post the entire thing. FreeSp is on visible on the popup window when the spin is free. After you click the button (to use your free spin) the DOM updates to costSp. My button checks to see which DIV element is visible and then update my button.

Comment: @mplungjan Also. this line 
const ById = id => document.getElementById(id);
 Breaks my script.

Comment: Your code does not check if the button is visible. If document.getElementById("FreeSp") always return a button, then there is not need for the `var FreeSp = freeforSpin.querySelector("#FreeSp");` test, just a need for a visibility test

Comment: @mplungjan There is a lot of other things going on inside this script but I'll try to break them out.
One second, let me make a pastebin

Comment: @mplungjan If you are free we can move this to chat but here is more code, 
https://pastebin.com/0i1dDS7U

Comment: If you wrote this yourself, why not set a global var to true or false when the thing is available? Also your eventListeners could be decimated if you delegated from a container

Comment: @mplungjan This is a script that was written by a WAY smarter gentleman than I and it's very detailed. He no longer plays the game and doesn't do anything with the script anymore and since I love learning things and playing this game too I thought I would update a few things. This being one of them. How can we chat outside of here (I don't have 20 reputation yet. Also I can share the full script if you would like to see it.

Comment: You can create a collaborative jsfiddle and post the link here

Comment: @mplungjanI I don't think a jsfiddle would work as this game is played off of facebook and the js is being added to a 3rd party "Violentmonkey" plugin on FF. I don't know how to get you what is needed to figure it out. The game is called Kingdoms of camelot if you would like to check it out.